# Excel Array Formula

Tags: arrays, excel, formulas

I've previously created an Excel array formula such as follows:

```
X13: =SUM(IF($F13>H13:R13,1,0))+IF(F13>F9,1,0)+SUM(IF($F13>T13:U13,1,0))+IF(T13>U13,1,0)
```

When applying this formula down a column and hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, the array formula produced formulas in the rows below as follows:

```
Y13: =SUM(IF($F14>H14:R14,1,0))+IF(F14>F10,1,0)+SUM(IF($F14>T14:U14,1,0))+IF(T14>U14,1,0)
Z13: =SUM(IF($F15>H15:R15,1,0))+IF(F15>F11,1,0)+SUM(IF($F15>T15:U15,1,0))+IF(T15>U15,1,0)
...
```

However, now that I'm trying to update the formula, when I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, I get the original formula showing up in all cells.

```
X13: =SUM(IF($F13>H13:R13,1,0))+IF(F13>F9,1,0)+SUM(IF($F13>T13:U13,1,0))+IF(T13>U13,1,0)
Y13: =SUM(IF($F13>H13:R13,1,0))+IF(F13>F9,1,0)+SUM(IF($F13>T13:U13,1,0))+IF(T13>U13,1,0)
Z13: =SUM(IF($F13>H13:R13,1,0))+IF(F13>F9,1,0)+SUM(IF($F13>T13:U13,1,0))+IF(T13>U13,1,0)
...
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: You need to select all the original cells when you alter the formula

Comment: only select the first formula, fix it, hit Ctrl-Shift-enter, then drag it down.  do not highlight all of the formula first.

Comment: THANKS!  This last suggestion worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need for an array formula.  This formula will perform the exact same functionality and it is not an array formula:

```
=(F13>F9)+COUNTIF(H13:R13,"<"&$F13)+COUNTIF(T13:U13,"<"&$F13)+(T13>U13)
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to have the automatic calculation: `Preferences/Calculation/Automatically`. Refresh with <kbd>F9</kbd>